# How to achieve this type of darkened watercolor border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

I am using illustrator to make watercolor shapes. I am able to make the shapes with watercolor background.. but they look too flat on the edges.
I actually want them to look like these 2 sample sources:
[image: sample1]
[image: sample2]

As you can see the ring and star have a nice watercolor esque borders even with roughness. I can create the roughness but I want to actually darken the border for which I'm confused how.
I am comfortable with photoshop and illustrator both.